# Why is my array out of bounds?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, in-app-purchase, xcode8

I am trying to incorporate an in-app purchase. For some reason I am getting a fatal error that states 'fatal error: Index out of range' with an array that holds the SKProduct products. I have one nonconsumable in app purchase, but may decide to add more later. I am trying to access the PREMIUM_PRODUCT_ID product so I can make a purchase. The error occurs when the purchaseMyProduct function is called. Any ideas in why the iapProducts array is out of bounds? Thanks for your help!
The fatal error occurs on this line `purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[0])`

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit


class Settings: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate,
SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    let PREMIUM_PRODUCT_ID = "---------------"

    var productID = ""
    var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()
    var nonConsumablePurchaseMade = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")



    @IBOutlet weak var adsBtn: UIButton!
    @IBAction func restorePurchase(_ sender: Any) {
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()

        // Check your In-App Purchases
        print("NON CONSUMABLE PURCHASE MADE: \(nonConsumablePurchaseMade)")


        // Fetch IAP Products available
        fetchAvailableProducts()

        UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                    message: "You've successfully restored your purchase!",
                    delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
    }

    @IBAction func review(_ sender: Any) {
        UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "-----------------")! as URL)

    }


    @IBAction func removeAds(_ sender: Any) {
        //UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "----------------")! as URL)

        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[0])

    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.


    }

   ...

    func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {
        nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
        UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")

        /*UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                    message: "You've successfully restored your purchase!",
                    delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()*/
    }

    func fetchAvailableProducts()  {

        // Put here your IAP Products ID's
        let productIdentifiers = NSSet(objects:
                                       PREMIUM_PRODUCT_ID
        )

        productsRequest = SKProductsRequest(productIdentifiers: productIdentifiers as! Set<String>)
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }

    func productsRequest (_ request:SKProductsRequest, didReceive response:SKProductsResponse) {
        if (response.products.count > 0) {
            iapProducts = response.products

            // 1st IAP Product (Consumable) ------------------------------------
            let firstProduct = response.products[0] as SKProduct

            // Get its price from iTunes Connect
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = .behavior10_4
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
            numberFormatter.locale = firstProduct.priceLocale
            let price1Str = numberFormatter.string(from: firstProduct.price)

            // Show its description
            //consumableLabel.text = firstProduct.localizedDescription + "\nfor just \(price1Str!)"
            // ------------------------------------------------



            // 2nd IAP Product (Non-Consumable) ------------------------------
            let secondProd = response.products[0] as SKProduct

            // Get its price from iTunes Connect
            numberFormatter.locale = secondProd.priceLocale
            let price2Str = numberFormatter.string(from: secondProd.price)

            // Show its description
            //nonConsumableLabel.text = secondProd.localizedDescription + "\nfor just \(price2Str!)"
            // ------------------------------------
        }
    }

    func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }
    func purchaseMyProduct(product: SKProduct) {
        if self.canMakePurchases() {
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
            productID = product.productIdentifier


            // IAP Purchases dsabled on the Device
        } else {
            UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                        message: "Purchases are disabled in your device!",
                        delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
        }
    }

    func paymentQueue(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {
        for transaction:AnyObject in transactions {
            if let trans = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction {
                switch trans.transactionState {

                case .purchased:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)

                    // The Consumable product (10 coins) has been purchased -> gain 10 extra coins!
                    if productID == PREMIUM_PRODUCT_ID {

                        // Save your purchase locally (needed only for Non-Consumable IAP)
                        nonConsumablePurchaseMade = true
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(nonConsumablePurchaseMade, forKey: "nonConsumablePurchaseMade")

                        //premiumLabel.text = "Premium version PURCHASED!"

                        UIAlertView(title: "IAP Tutorial",
                                    message: "You've successfully unlocked the Premium version!",
                                    delegate: nil,
                                    cancelButtonTitle: "OK").show()
                    }

                    break

                case .failed:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break
                case .restored:
                    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
                    break

                default: break
                }}}
    }

}
```

Comment: That error means that you're trying to access a non-existent element of an array (for example, the 4th item of an array that is 3 items long). On which line does the error occur?

Comment: Please edit your question in two ways. (1) Remove any code that isn't related to your issue - we really can't wade through all this code. (2) Point exactly to the line of code giving you the error. (You may be, or it may be clear, but with how much code you've given us, it's really hard to tell. BONUS: Have you set any breakpoints in your code? Something where you may know what array, and what the contents are when the error happens?

Comment: ok I will update it

Comment: @BrandonSmith please take your time to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and thereafter consider updating this question. Your code "snippet" above still contains very large amounts of code, and you will have a hard time finding someone willing to even begin to answer in its current form. Also the process of creating minimal examples of ones issues is very valuable, and its likely that you'll solve the problem yourself once you break it down.

Comment: I updated the question, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is way too long, so I took the liberty of making an educated guess what is relevant:

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class Settings: UIViewController, SKProductsRequestDelegate,
SKPaymentTransactionObserver {

    var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()

    @IBAction func removeAds(_ sender: Any) {
        purchaseMyProduct(product: iapProducts[0])

    }
}
```

When you declare `iapProducts`, you are creating an empty array that contains no values.

Then, in your `removeAds` function, you are telling it to do something with the first element.

I am going to take a wild guess that nothing exists, so you are forcing it to access an object that doesn't exist.

Try the following and see if it fixes your issue.

```
var iapProducts: [SKProduct]?

@IBAction func removeAds(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let product = iapProducts?.first else { return }

    purchaseMyProduct(product: product)
}
```

This accomplishes two things:

1. It makes your `[SKProduct]` array an optional
2. The guard statement safely unwraps the first product, so only if one exists, will it try to call your `purchaseMyProduct` function. Otherwise, it just exits